# Picking a pseudo random number generator

Tags: pseudo-random-generators

I'm looking for what I think is a random number generator, it should have the following properties, but I'm completely uncertain how to look for a suitable algorithm. I'd appreciate either pointers to a specific algorithm, a class of them, places for starting my research, or an explanation of why what I'm looking for isn't feasible.

Given a set of N items (item 1, item 2, … item N) I'm looking for what I presume is a pseudo random number generator that will:

- for a given positive number input (A) return a deterministically chosen item (item B) — `g(A) = B`
- where B is always between 1 and N inclusive
- where two consecutive inputs will never return the same output — `g(A) != g(A+1)`
- where `g(A)` is frequently *not* equal to `g(A+N)` — ie. it's not just a repeating sequence
- any N consecutive outputs have a reasonably high probability of being the full set of 1 to N.
- there's a broadly uniform chance of getting any B for a given A.
- `g(A)` can be calculated without knowing `g(A-1)`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are all of those requirements necessary?  Here is why I ask:  A true-random source would not meet those requirements.  Normally a pseudorandom source is intended to mimic true randomness.  If a true-random source would not meet those requirements, then that's a possible indication that the requirements might be too strong; or alternatively it might be a sign that perhaps we should not call the resulting algorithm a pseudorandom number generator.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "any N consecutive outputs"?  Do you mean that g(1), g(2), ..., g(N) have a high probability of being the full set 1,2,..,N?

Comment: Yeah; these requirements are necessary given my use case — but my use of the word "random" probably isn't!

And yes, your clarification is also accurate — g(1) … g(N) has a high probability of including all of 1 … N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility which seems to tick most of the boxes is to construct an indexed family of functions $h_i : N \rightarrow N$ with the property that for all $i$, $h_i$ is a permutation (i.e. a bijection or isomorphism). Then:

$$g(a) = h_{\left\lfloor a/N \right\rfloor}(a \bmod N)$$

This has the property that $g(Nk)$ to $g(Nk + N - 1)$ produces all of the numbers from $1$ to $N$, but the next $N$ values are a different permutation.

If $N = 2^{2b}$ for some $b$, constructing permutations is surprisingly easy by using [Feistel networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher), and by using operations other than exclusive or (e.g. modular arithmetic) and forgoing some symmetry, the construction can be generalised for any $N$ which isn't prime.

The one requirement that this doesn't solve is that it doesn't absolutely guarantee that $g(i+1) \ne g(i)$ if you cross a permutation boundary. But it's unlikely; you can expect it to happen roughly once in every $N^3$ values.

The only other thing I can think of is to perhaps do something clever with [de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence), but I don't believe we know a way to pseudo-randomly index them.

Comment: I realize this is super-nitpicky, but when you write $N \to N$, do you mean $\{1,\dots,N\} \to \{1,\dots,N\}$?  (And not $\mathbb{N}$, I presume?)

Comment: @D.W. Correct. I'm the kind of annoying person who uses a natural number to mean a finite set with the same cardinality. Abuse of notation.